# How to identify the permutations of an object, giving importance to the order of the elements in R

Tags: r, permutation

i need your help to identify all the permutations of an object, but taking into account also the order of the elements.

For example, for the object x <- c(1,2,3), i need to find all this permutations :

*permutation_1*:    1   2   3

*permutation_2*:    1   3   2

*permutation_3*:    2   1   3

*permutation_4*:    2   3   1

*permutation_5*:    3   1   2

*permutation_6*:    3   2   1

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Comment: This is called permutations and not combinations

Comment: just do `gtools::permutations(n = 3, r = 3, v = x)`